# Where do I put my Grunt compiled Ember.js Templates in my HTML file?

Tags: ember.js, express, handlebars.js, grunt-ember-templates

I'm working on a simple Ember.js and Express app and up to now all my templates have been in my `index.html` file. This is my first time using Grunt for anything much less precompile templates. (I'm using [Grunt-Ember-Handlebars](https://github.com/yaymukund/grunt-ember-handlebars) to tackle the compiling)

I've moved all my templates into a `handlebars` folder and they compile into `templates.js` in the same folder.

**My question is this: where do I include the script tag linking to `templates.js` in my HTML file?**

Here is how I have all my scrips laid out:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>    
  <script src="../js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/libs/ember-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>

    <!-- APP  -->
    <script src="templates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
      <script src='../js/router.js'></script>
      <script src='../js/controllers/controllers.js'></script>
```

My path to my `templates.js` file is correct so thats not an issue. But it always returns with errors stating:

> Assertion failed: Could not find "index" template or view.

The only file I know I need to include it after is my `ember.js` file. Other than that, it makes no difference in error output if I include it after or before any files in my App.

Thanks for the help ahead of time!

**Edit:**
Here is my Gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ember_handlebars: {
    compile: {
      options: {
        namespace: "emberApp.TEMPLATES"
      },
      files: {
        "views/templates.js" : "handlebars/*.hbs"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: how are your templates formatted? are you including script tags within files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter where to put them. Seems like they have wrong naming.

1. Put templates into `templates`
2. Name them correctly (`application.hbs` for *application* template)
3. Use this grunt command

`ember_handlebars: {
    options: {
      processName: function(name) {
        return name.replace(/(templates\/|\.hbs)/g, '');
      }
    },
    files: {
      "templates.js": "templates/**/*.hbs",
    }`

Comment: @JDillon522 open templates.js it should have string like `this["Ember"]["TEMPLATES"]["application"]` pay attention to `["application"]` in your case it seems to be different

Comment: oohh that might be my problem. I have `this["emberApp"]["TEMPLATES"]["handlebars/application.hbs"]`

Comment: @JDillon522 yes that's why we need `processName`. I fyou want to keep templates in `handlebars` directory change regexrp like so: `return name.replace(/(handlebars\/|\.hbs)/g, '');`